# shell: Do wildcards guarantee alphabetical order?

Tags: bash, dash-shell

When I have the files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` is it **guaranteed** that

```
cat *.txt > all_files.txt
```

or

```
cat ?.txt > all_files.txt
```

will combine the files in alphabetical order?

(In all my tests, the alphabetical order was preserved, but I'm not sure because for example with `ls` the order is undefined and need not be alphabetic - but it often is, because the files have often been written to the directory alphabetically)

Comment: More or less dupe from serverfault: http://serverfault.com/q/122737/240915 (the short answer is "yes")

Comment: I don't think it can be a duplicate if it's on another stack-exchange site. When I posed the question I did not see any duplicates in the list (because it only shows entries from stack-overlow of course), and it is clearly on-topic for programming.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way - there's just an answer to your question there :)

Comment: "The pathnames are in sort order as defined by the current setting of the LC_COLLATE category, see the XBD specification, LC_COLLATE". http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/glob.html

Comment: Shell expansion is alphabetical; `ls` can sort chronologically or alphabetically, up or down, depending on options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it depends on the *locale*.  The order is dictated by the collation sequence in the locale, which can be changed using the `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_ALL` environment variables.  Note that bash behaves differently in this respect to some other shells (e.g. Korn shell).

If you have a locale setting of `C` or `POSIX` then it will be in character set order.  Otherwise you will probably only notice a difference with mixed case letters, e.g. the sequence for en_ locales is aAbBcC ... xXyYzZ.  For example see http://collation-charts.org/fc6/fc6.en_GB.iso885915.html.

Available locales may be listed using `locale -a`.

Edit:  another variable `LANG` is available, but it is generally not used much nowadays.  According to the Single UNIX Specification it is used: *in the absence of the LC_ALL and other LC_* ... environment variables*.